# Link component en React que no aparezca en el Home component

Tags: reactjs, router

Tengo mi componente principal desde donde hago el ruteo

```
Class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Links />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
        </div>
      </Router>
     );
   }
  }
```

Pero y el componente Links solo tiene lo siguiente:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Links = () => (
  <nav>
    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
  </nav>
 );

export default Links;
```

Lo que quiero es que solo aparezca cuando rendereo el componente Usuario, cosa que al clickear vuelva al Home, pero no quiero que aparezca cuando estoy en Home porque es innecesario.

Se puede hacer?
Gracias¡

Comment: Mete `Links` dentro de tu componente de `Users`, por qué lo dejas directamente en el App si solo quieres que aparezca en usuarios?

Comment: Renderiza el componente links solo en el componente Users

Answer (score 1):

Muy buenas, por lo que entiendo quieres que solo se muestre el enlace en la pestaña de usuarios, bueno pues hay varias soluciones muy simples.

> Un punto importante a destacar, es que estás usando **Router** en vez de usar **BrowserRouter** lo cual no es una buena práctica si no creas tu mismo el componente history del cual depende el **Router** de React.

---

## 1. **Usando el componente NavLink en vez de Link**

En esta opción lo único necesario es el uso de CSS para que este método surta efecto.

**App.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

import './App.css';

const NavLinks = props => (
  <nav>
    <NavLink exact strict to="/">Home</NavLink>
  </nav>
)

const Home = props => (
  <div>
    Home
  </div>
)

const Users = props => (
  <div>
    Users
  </div>
)

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <div id="app-bar">
            <NavLinks />
          </div>
          <div id="app-router">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact strict path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route exact strict path="/users" component={Users} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

> Cuando definimos **NavLinks** es necesario especificar las variables exact y strict para que nuestro elemento funcione a la perfección.

**App.css**

```
nav a.active {
  display: none;
}
```

> Cuando usamos Navlinks en **ReactJS**, en caso de que la ruta sea exactamente igual al path que contiene el elemento **NavLink**, adopta una clase llamada active, la cual la podemos usar para estilizar cuando estamos en la URl que representa ese **NavLink**

[image: Ejemplo 1]

---

## 2. **Renderizando el componente Links solamente dentro del componente Users**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

import './App.css';

const Links = props => (
  <nav>
    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
  </nav>
)

const Home = props => (
  <div>
    Home
  </div>
)

const Users = props => (
  <div>
        <Links />
        Users
  </div>
)

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact strict path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact strict path="/users" component={Users} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

[image: Ejemplo 2]

---

### **Espero que te sea de gran ayuda!!**

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo anidar tus rutas en el componente Switch de React Router. Luego prueba colocar el exact prop en la ruta de users. Te quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    <Route path="/users" exact component={Users} />      
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```